# Subversion: Getting List of Version-Controlled Files in Current Directory

Tags: svn

I want to write a script to get a list of all the version-controlled files in the current directory (no recursion).  Is there a way to do this?  This is for Linux.

Comment: Like `svn list`? What are your exact specs and what problems have you faced?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this command.  `svn list | grep -v /` pretty much does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of existing subcommands either from the command line:

```
C:\Test>svn help
usage: svn <subcommand> [options] [args]
Subversion command-line client, version 1.8.8.
Type 'svn help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Type 'svn --version' to see the program version and RA modules
  or 'svn --version --quiet' to see just the version number.

Most subcommands take file and/or directory arguments, recursing
on the directories.  If no arguments are supplied to such a
command, it recurses on the current directory (inclusive) by default.

Available subcommands:
   add
   blame (praise, annotate, ann)
   cat
   changelist (cl)
[...]
```

... or from the [official Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.html). You probably want **svn list**:

> svn list (ls) — List directory entries in the repository.

For automated processing, you might also be interested in the `--xml` flag:

> `--xml` Prints output in XML format. XML schemas for the output (in
>   RELAX NG format) are maintained in the subversion/svn/schema/
>   directory of the Subversion source tree.

As far as I can tell, there's no option to omit directories but the output always distinguish them in some way. Plain output adds a trailing slash:

```
C:\Test>svn list
Bar.txt
Foo/
```

XML output has s `kind` attribute:

```
<entry
   kind="file">
<name>Bar.txt</name>
<size>1113</size>
<commit
   revision="802">
<author>alvaro</author>
<date>2014-03-10T20:36:52.111059Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
<entry
   kind="dir">
<name>Foo</name>
<commit
   revision="795">
<author>alvaro</author>
<date>2014-02-05T20:24:50.508825Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
```